# HTML check box row select code

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help please.

Below is my code for an HTML table.

It has multiple checkboxes.

What I want to do is that once the "HOLD"check-box is clicked, I want to grab the shipment number field for the selected row so that I can do some AJAX using that number.

Can someone please help me out

```
<table id='consignment_list' class="consignment_list_tbl">
<colgroup width='20'> </colgroup>
<?php
if ($user->getUserAccount() == "") echo "<colgroup width='30'> </colgroup>";
?>
<!-- table head -->
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Select All <input type='checkbox' name='checkall'
onclick='checkedAll(deleteConsignments1);'>  </th>
<th>Status</th>
<?php
if ($user->getUserAccount() == "") echo "<th>Account</th>";
?>
<th>Packages</th>
<th>HAWB</th>
<th>AWB</th>
<th>Consignee Name</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Weight</th>
<th>No of Pieces</th>
<th>Piece ID</th>
<th>Hold</th>
<th>Heavy Weight</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!-- table foot -->
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<?php
if ($user->getUserAccount() == "") echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
?>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<!-- table body -->

<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($consignment_array as $ct_idx => $consignment)
{
foreach ($consignment->getParcels(true) as $parcel)
{
if($parcel->getProcessed()==1) {
continue;
}

$status = $consignment->getStatus();
$id= $consignment->getId(); 
?> 
<tr style="background-color: red;color: black;" id="<?php  echo $parcel-
>getLicencePlate()?>" 
name="<?php echo $consignment->getAwb()?>">
<td id="c"> <input type=checkbox id= "deleteConsignments1"
name="deleteConsignments[]" onclick="row_color(this)" value="<?php  
$consignment->getId()?> "  /> </td>

<td><?php echo Consignment::stateText($status); ?></td>
<?php
if ($user->getUserAccount() == "") echo "<td>" . $consignment->getAccount()  
. "</td>";
?>
<td class="colPieces"><?php echo $consignment->getNumberPieces(); ?></td>
<td><a href='../main/consignment_edit.php?from=client&id=<?php echo  
$consignment->getId(); ?>' style="color: white;">
<?php echo $consignment->getHawb(); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $consignment->getAWB(); ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $consignment->getContact(); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $consignment->getCity(); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $consignment->getCountry();; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $consignment->getWeight(); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $consignment->getNumberPieces(); ?>
<td><?php echo $parcel->getLicencePlate(); ?></td>
<td><input type=checkbox onclick="row_colorHold(this)" name="hold[]"   
id="hold1" value="<?php echo $consignment->getId(); ?>" ></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='heavyweight[]' id="heavyweight" value="<?
 php echo $consignment->getId(); ?>"></td>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
 }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you just create a subset of the client-side code demonstrating the problem and place it in a fiddle?

Comment: below is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fhgmsg5L/

I want to fetch the piece ID of the selected row using the "HOLD" checkbox

Comment: Your question suggests a CSS/Styling issue, but you want actual functionality. Please change the title of your question to be more relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/y0vhw7cu/

Note that it also includes jQuery as you tagged question with it.

It's really simple:

A class "hold" has been added to your checkbox:

```
<input class="hold" type=checkbox onclick="row_colorHold(this)" name="hold[]" id="hold1" value="<?php echo $consignment->getId(); ?>"
>
```

and then we just do this:

```
// make sure the document (your markup) is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // detect click of any element which has the .hold classs
    $(".hold").click(function() {
        // when it happens, assign value of the clicked element to variable
        var value = $(this).val();
        // do whatever we want with this variable:)
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

If you want to do more stuff with elements, they can all be wrapped in this single `$(document).ready`

EDIT: This example will of course always show `<?php echo $consignment->getId(); ?>` when you click it, but when you apply this to your actual code, PHP will dynamically replace it with appropriate value.

EDIT 2: https://jsfiddle.net/xtr2peu3/

As per your comment, here we do something a little bit different. We're attaching `.hold` class to the `<td>` which contains the "hold" checkbox:

```
<td class="hold">
<input type=checkbox onclick="row_colorHold(this)" name="hold[]" id="hold1" value="<?php echo $consignment->getId(); ?>" ></td>
```

Then we attach a `click` event handler to it, and when it gets clicked, we grab the textual content of the previous element:

```
$(".hold").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).prev().text();
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: This is partially fine.
The popup which displays is NOT showing 4444 as the value of Piece ID.
I want he popup to show the Piece ID value.
Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer, please let me know if it helps, or if you need further clarification.

Comment: Well I want the Piece ID which has a static value of 4444.$consignment->getId(); is assigned to a different TD.

Comment: Edited answer with new fiddle which does exactly that.

Comment: Thank you that worked great. Can you please explain what  $(this).prev().text(); does for my understanding?

Comment: $(this) is the element that you clicked. prev() selects the previous element, and text() grabs the text inside selected element.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to check if the checkbox is selected or not? I tried $(this).is(':checked') but its always giving as false.

Comment: That's because in your case $(this) represents the <td> which cannot be checked. But if you try this it should work: alert($(this).find('input').is(':checked'))

Comment: Explanation: it starts from $(this), which is <td>, then it finds the <input> inside of it, and then it checks is it checked.

Comment: Is there a way to get the background color of the selected TR ( row ) ? Thanks